# How would you secure a lamp socket in a wooden hole?

Tags: lamp, socket

Suppose you have a wooden block. You drill one hole through for the cable, and then another shallower to put the socket into that holds the lamp. How would you forward to secure the socket. I've watched a couple tutorials and they just loosely put it in there which I think is a bad idea because I want to have it secured.

[image]

Comment: You should show a picture of the socket that you intend to use. That will be key to getting suggestions for securing it in place.

Comment: Have you searches threaded lamp rod?

Comment: How large is this and what kind of socket? One type of basic socket screws onto a piece of threaded pipe which the wire comes in though, and a classic approach for table lamps is just to make the hole in the wood the right size to screw the pipe into...

Comment: @mikes And how do I secure the lamp rod?

Comment: @keshlam So you simply make it wide enough that you can barely push the pipe/rod through it? Is this really an acceptable way of securing things; just push it in there? 

Oh you are thinking of the pipe going into the hole I've sent in the picture, and the bulb being elevated off the ground? I'm thinking of directly placing the bulb on top of the wood. I don't know if we are on the same page anymore. Sorry.

Comment: Just barely smaller so the threads on the pipe can grip the surrounding would firmly and screw into it. I don't have mine handy, but if you websearch "high school woodworking water pump lamp" or some combination of those keywords you'll likely find an infinite number of samples and a couple of different plans for mine. Or just search "wood lamp plans" and you're likely to find an incredible number of them.

Comment: The lamp rod is available at home centers or a lamp repair shop.  You would need a washer for each end. The top would be long enough to  screw the lamp socket on to the exposed threads above the nut.

Answer (score 1):

If you can find it, a socket like this is what I have used on a ceramic pot turned into a lamp.

[image]

You can also get sockets that have a thread at the bottom (from another lamp)

[image]

Comment: Wood would have to be threaded for a threaded socket to be used, right? I can't simply brute-foce such a large threading into wood, can I?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the socket:

1. glue
2. screws
3. some have an internal thread that you can use.